# I need to update a package

Tags: r, package, runtime-error, updates

I want to install the package sp, but then R shows me this message:

```
> install.packages("sp")
```

> Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your R session? It works fine in my RStudio.

If you have issues installing the package from the CRAN Repository, try this:

```
devtools::install_github("edzer/sp")
```

It will return these outputs

```
Downloading GitHub repo edzer/sp@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSOAQPV\remotes242444575da6\edzer-sp-2ace7ca/DESCRIPTION' (952ms)
-  preparing 'sp': (8.6s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (2s)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'sp_1.4-5.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'sp' ...
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Rcentroid.c -o Rcentroid.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c gcdist.c -o gcdist.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c pip.c -o pip.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c pip2.c -o pip2.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c sp_xports.c -o sp_xports.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c surfaceArea.c -o surfaceArea.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c zerodist.c -o zerodist.o
/mingw32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sp.dll tmp.def Rcentroid.o gcdist.o init.o pip.o pip2.o sp_xports.o surfaceArea.o zerodist.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/00LOCK-sp/00new/sp/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Rcentroid.c -o Rcentroid.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c gcdist.c -o gcdist.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c pip.c -o pip.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c pip2.c -o pip2.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c sp_xports.c -o sp_xports.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c surfaceArea.c -o surfaceArea.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c zerodist.c -o zerodist.o
/mingw64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sp.dll tmp.def Rcentroid.o gcdist.o init.o pip.o pip2.o sp_xports.o surfaceArea.o zerodist.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/00LOCK-sp/00new/sp/libs/x64
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'sp'
    finding HTML links ... done
    00sp                                    html  
    CRS-class                               html  
    DMS-class                               html  
    GridTopology-class                      html  
    Line-class                              html  
    Line                                    html  
    Lines-class                             html  
    Polygon-class                           html  
    Polygons-class                          html  
    Rlogo                                   html  
    Spatial-class                           html  
REDIRECT:topic   coordinates<-,Spatial-method -> Spatial-class.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   [[<-,Spatial,ANY,missing-method -> Spatial-class.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   [<-,Spatial-method -> Spatial-class.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   $<-,Spatial-method -> Spatial-class.html [ FAIL ]
    SpatialGrid-class                       html  
    SpatialGrid                             html  
    SpatialGridDataFrame-class              html  
    SpatialGridDataFrame                    html  
    SpatialLines-class                      html  
    SpatialLines                            html  
    SpatialLinesDataFrame-class             html  
    SpatialMultiPoints-class                html  
REDIRECT:topic   $<-,SpatialMultiPoints,character-method -> SpatialMultiPoints-class.html [ FAIL ]
    SpatialMultiPoints                      html  
    SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame-class       html  
    SpatialPixels-class                     html  
    SpatialPixelsDataFrame-class            html  
    SpatialPoints-class                     html  
REDIRECT:topic   $<-,SpatialPoints,character-method -> SpatialPoints-class.html [ FAIL ]
    SpatialPoints                           html  
    SpatialPointsDataFrame-class            html  
    SpatialPolygons-class                   html  
    SpatialPolygons                         html  
    SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class          html  
    addattr                                 html  
    aggregate                               html  
    as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology         html  
    as.SpatialPolygons.PolygonsList         html  
    asciigrid                               html  
    bbox                                    html  
    bpy.colors                              html  
    bubble                                  html  
    char2dms                                html  
    compassRose                             html  
    coordinates-methods                     html  
REDIRECT:topic   coordinates<-,data.frame-method -> coordinates-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    coordinates                             html  
REDIRECT:topic   coordinates<- -> coordinates.html [ FAIL ]
    coordnames-methods                      html  
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<- -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialPoints,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialMultiPoints,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialLines,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,Lines,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,Line,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialPolygons,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,GridTopology,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialGrid,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   coordnames<-,SpatialPixels,character-method -> coordnames-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    degaxis                                 html  
    dimensions                              html  
    disaggregate                            html  
    flip                                    html  
    geometry-methods                        html  
REDIRECT:topic   geometry<- -> geometry-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   geometry<-,data.frame,Spatial-method -> geometry-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    gridded-methods                         html  
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<- -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<- -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<-,Spatial,ANY-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<-,SpatialGrid,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<-,SpatialGridDataFrame,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<-,SpatialPixels,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   fullgrid<-,SpatialPixelsDataFrame,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialGrid,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialGridDataFrame,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPixels,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPixelsDataFrame,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPoints,list-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPoints,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPointsDataFrame,list-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,SpatialPointsDataFrame,logical-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,data.frame,GridTopology-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,data.frame,character-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   gridded<-,data.frame,formula-method -> gridded-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    gridindex2nb                            html  
    gridlines                               html  
    image                                   html  
    is.projected                            html  
REDIRECT:topic   proj4string<- -> is.projected.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   proj4string<-,Spatial,CRS-method -> is.projected.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   proj4string<-,Spatial,character-method -> is.projected.html [ FAIL ]
    loadmeuse                               html  
    mapasp                                  html  
    merge                                   html  
    meuse                                   html  
    meuse.grid                              html  
    meuse.grid_ll                           html  
    meuse.riv                               html  
    over                                    html  
    panel                                   html  
    point.in.polygon                        html  
    polygons-methods                        html  
REDIRECT:topic   polygons<-,data.frame,SpatialPolygons-method -> polygons-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    polygons                                html  
REDIRECT:topic   polygons<- -> polygons.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   Previous alias or file overwritten by alias: C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/00LOCK-sp/00new/sp/help/polygons.html
    recenter-methods                        html  
    select.spatial                          html  
    sp-deprecated                           html  
    spChFIDs-methods                        html  
REDIRECT:topic   spChFIDs<- -> spChFIDs-methods.html [ FAIL ]
REDIRECT:topic   spChFIDs<-,Spatial-method -> spChFIDs-methods.html [ FAIL ]
    spDistsN1                               html  
    spTransform                             html  
    spplot                                  html  
    spsample                                html  
    stack                                   html  
    surfaceArea                             html  
    zerodist                                html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (sp)
```

After the install finishes, load the package by

```
library(sp)
```

Otherwise, if it still return errors. Try downloading the package from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) and install them to RStudio manually

Comment: If the package was previously installed, you can often find it in your libraries/ folder and delete it. Then try again. Often works for me for stubborn packages.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late. I suffered the same issue. Uninstalling and Installing the package again worked for me.